# XSS into Javascript?

Tags: xss, javascript

Im testing an application for XSS. My input from an HTTP request is being reflected into an inline script in the response. Specifically it is being reflected into an object.

I am trying to escape the `"` and `}` in order to generate a successful XSS. The application is URL encoding (%) these characters, and I am stuck inside the string still.

Are there any work arounds for such a use case. I know HTML entity encoding  (<) is usually the preferred way to protect against XSS, but I'm not sure if the % encoding described above is sufficient since the context is within JS.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide an example URL and the javascript code that it results in?

Comment: if it's stuck inside a script from an ajax call, it shouldn't pose a problem; you can't break out of a string with a `</script>` tag that's been injected via the DOM; it needs to be malformed html served by a server as html.